# Клонирование массивов в PHP

Tags: php, массивы, ссылки

В проекте нужно производить вычисления с промежуточным сохранением каждого этапа в переменные. После чего собрать все результаты в массив с ключами, одноименными имени переменной. Потом передать массив в другую функцию и там перебрать, изменяя значения только внутри функции, не меняя оригинальных.

```
// Решил, что в начале работы обнулю все переменные и соберу ссылки на них в массив
$var1 = $var2 = $var3 = 0;
$busket['var1'] = &$var1;
$busket['var2'] = &$var2;
$busket['var3'] = &$var3;

// далее идут вычисления 
$var1 = ...;
$var2 = ...;
$var3 = ...;

// передаём массив в другую функцию
$niceOutput = string_formatting($busket);

// и вот тут переменные $var1 .. $var3 уже изменённые, 
// чего быть не должно
```

А вот внутри функции мне уже нужно работать с копией массива, у которой значения не связаны ссылками с исходными переменными.

```
function string_formatting($busket) {
    // вот так скопировать не получается, значения всё равно передаются ссылками
    $copyBusket = $busket;
    unset($busket);
    foreach ($copyBusket as $name => &$value) {
        // меняем $value
    }
}
```

Интересуюсь исключительно в образовательных целях, чтоб понять как отвязывать ссылки на переменные, т.к. задачу уже решил по-другому.

Comment: А зачем вы вообще ссылки используете? Работайте с переменными, а не ссылками на них.

Comment: @Visman, судя по всему ссылки - чтобы объявить массив заранее, а дальше по ходу программы при изменении переменных будет изменяться и массив. Только что мешает `$copyBusket ` в цикле заполнять, а не через присваивание? Или через `array_flip(array_flip($busket));`

Comment: @BOPOH array_flip есть опасность потерять часть данных. А как еще скопировать, кроме перебора в цикле?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно клонировать массив через создание объекта `ArrayObject` с последующим вызовом метода `getArrayCopy()`.

```
$obj = new ArrayObject($busket);
$copyBusket = $obj->getArrayCopy();
```

В этом случае `$copyBusket` и `$arr` уже не будут ссылками на один и тот же массив.

Comment: я уже и забыл, зачем мне это надо. но спасибо, оно :)